# switch statement not executing properly

Tags: java

I'm working on an assignment for a class, so I can't post my exact code but I can give a similar example. I'm trying to build a banking system and a menu will be displayed first to get the user to pick what they would like to do. My problem is that when the user enters a number the methods don't execute and the menu prints out again.

Example code:

```
while(choose != 4){
System.out.println("Please choose from the following options");
System.out.println("1. Do this");
System.out.println("2. Do this!");
System.out.println("3. Do THIS!");
System.out.println("4. Close application")

Scanner scanny = new Scanner(System.in);
choose = scanny.nextInt();
switch(choose)
{  
   case 1:
        method1();
        break;
   case 2:
        method2();
        break;
   case 3:
        method3();
        break;
   case 4:
        System.out.close();
        break();
   default:
        return;
}
}
Output:

Please choose from the following options:
1. Do this
2. Do this!
3. Do THIS!
4. Close application

(User enters 2)

2
Please choose from the following options:
1. Do this
2. Do this!
3. Do THIS!
4. Close application
```

I hope this makes sense.. any help is appreciated and I will gladly clear anything up!

Comment: How do you know the methods don't execute?

Comment: What is method2? Does it print anything? Eventually you should get back to the menu (after method2 completes).

Comment: @AjahnCharles method2 gets the user to input a number which will then be deposited into an account

Comment: @oo00ooaa They're asking you to post your methods. Without showing your methods, we can't confirm much based on your code.

Comment: Please show the methods in your question

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes to what you had, and the program below should give you a template for the switch you want. The big change was pulling the scanner creation outside of the loop, so it does not keep getting reinitialized. I also noticed your case 4 had break() not break.
I wrote pseudocode for the methods. Feel free to add back your own method calls, but leave in mine too for debugging first. Here's a working version.

```
int choose = 0;
Scanner scanny = new Scanner(System.in);
while (choose != 4) {
    System.out.println("Please choose from the following options");
    System.out.println("1. Do this");
    System.out.println("2. Do this!");
    System.out.println("3. Do THIS!");
    System.out.println("4. Close application");


    choose = scanny.nextInt();
    switch (choose) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("method 1");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("method 2");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("method 3");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.close();
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
}
```

Comment: given what your methods actually do, I think you may want to pass them scanny as a parameter. You don't want multiple things grabbing at your input.